I am unable to start ddev, throwing the below error[failed to mount local volume: mount ] while setting up new drupal project using ddev, docker
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-my-drupal-site_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/System/Volumes/Data/Users/vamshidhar.thella/Desktop/my-drupal-site:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-my-drupal-site_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=192.168.65.254,hard,nolock,wsize=32768,rsize=32768: connection refused
Failed to start my-drupal-site: composeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-my-drupal-site docker-compose -f /Users/vamshidhar.thella/Desktop/my-drupal-site/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml up -d', action='[up -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr=' Container ddev-my-drupal-site-db  Recreate
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-web  Recreate
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-web  Recreated
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-db  Recreated
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-db  Starting
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-web  Starting
Container ddev-my-drupal-site-db  Started
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-my-drupal-site_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/System/Volumes/Data/Users/vamshidhar.thella/Desktop/my-drupal-site:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-my-drupal-site_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=192.168.65.254,hard,nolock,wsize=32768,rsize=32768: connection refused'enter image description here
After entering ddev start, it is showing like failed to mount local volume: mount

NFS mounts are deprecated https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/install/performance/

I would upgrade DDEV as suggested on your screenshot, and rename ~/.ddev folder to something else, so it will be recreated on ddev start, and default global settings will be used. If this doesn't help, come over to Discord https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/support/ and provide ddev debug test output there.

As @stasadev says,

NFS mounts are deprecated
If you did want to use NFS, you'd need to have the NFS daemon running, as described in the docs. I don't think you do want that.
Upgrade DDEV to current.
Remove all performance_mode or nfs_mount_enabled lines from your project .ddev/config.yaml and your global ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml
ddev poweroff and then ddev start

Let us know how this goes for you.

Hi rfay,
I have changed performance_mode: nfs to performance_mode: default in ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml file. now ddev start is working for me, the error got resolved.
Thank you

Hmm, glad it's working. There is no performance_mode: default, but you can remove that line and you'll get the default.
